# Decimal to Binary converter can't calculate decimals greater than 1023

Tags: c, binary, decimal, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a function that converts decimal to binary. It works for values less than 1024, but I need it to work for 8-digit numbers as well. My function so far:

```
static long int decToBin(int dec)
{
  int bit;
  int k;
  long int bin = 0;

  for (bit = 32; bit >= 0; bit--)
  {
    k = dec >> bit;

    if (k & 1)
    {
       bin += exponentiate(10, bit);
    }
  }

  return bin;
}
```

I'm relatively new to bitwise stuff so it may be pretty obvious what the issue is, but I'd appreciate any help.

EDIT: I'm writing in C, using the GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger. ;-)

Comment: max value of int32 < 10^10.

Comment: max value of int64 < 10^20.

Comment: Shifting a 32-bit integer by 32 is undefined behaviour. Also, shifting a signed integer right is implementation defined, I believe.

Comment: exactly at 1024? that's 10 bits. makes no sense whatsoever. that's usually a good sign that you're not telling the truth.

Comment: What are you really trying to do ? Your function takes an int and returns a long int, so they're both binary representations of some number.

Comment: @nos: in this case the "binary representation" forms the printed binary representation if printed as a decimal number (eg: 11b -> 1011b is 11)

Comment: Ok, well I've got no reason to post make-believe code and watch a bunch of strangers spin their wheels, so I promise I'm telling the truth. I'm trying to write a function that takes in a decimal value from 0-99,999,999 and returns the binary representation of it. Ideally, in fact, I'd like it to take hex numbers and return the binary representation of that, but this is as far as I've made it so far. I'm new to C and I realize my programming skills need some work. I had hoped it might be something simple that someone more knowledgeable than myself could point out.

Comment: Hint: for bit-shifting operations you should prefer unsigned types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference

```
static void decToBin(int dec)
{
  int bit;
  int k;

  for (bit = 31; bit; bit--)
  {
    k = (unsigned int)dec >> bit;
    printf("%d", (k&1)?1:0);
  }
  k = (unsigned int)dec >> bit;
  printf("%d\n", (k&1)?1:0);
  return;
}
```

once you understand what this is doing, you can implement your own. Hint: You might need to allocate storage (32 bytes).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm trying to read up on the shifting operation, I get how it works with regular binary values but in testing it out on other numbers I'm still a little shaky on what it does. I think once I get that figured out, everything will make a lot more sense.